# How do I re-enable drag and drop (previously working) for Tor Browser 12?

Tags: drag-and-drop, tor, browser-security, tor-browser-bundle

Up until the latest update of the Tor Browser 12.0, I was able drag and drop images/links to my desktop.  My system is Windows 11.  With this release I get a red circle with a red diagonal line indicating it's disabled.  My install of the Tor Browser is simply the standard download from the torproject.org website, accepting the default settings.

I've searched through the release notes of v 12.0, done web searches for any drag and drop functionality change in Tor Browser 12.0 (or prior) and followed the possibilities with no success in re-enabling it.

I notice that I'm also not able to drag links to rearrange the bookmark toolbar, nor drag links from the address bar to the bookmark toolbar.  All other functionality remains, ie, I'm able to right-click to copy links to the clipboard, etc.  At this point I'm beginning to think this latest release has a bug, but find nothing in the most recent bug reports.

I've poured through the settings (including the "NoScript" extension) thinking that this change might be related to new security settings, but found nothing that seems to make a difference.  (Trusted sites are disabled for drag and drop also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was disabled deliberately: https://forum.torproject.net/t/drag-and-drop-protections-in-tor-browser-12-0/5854/1

> Since dragging URLs can trigger DNS requests via your OS, which bypasses Tor Browser’s proxy settings, we decided to disable the ability to drag URLs off-page for the time being.

The thread links to discussions how they're going to refine the feature (to allow drag and drop URLs) in future Tor releases.

Comment: The follow-up discussion found in your link regarding this makes a few good points regarding the clipboard and other issues revolving around dragging links.  The link is worth a read.